# close open connection to allow next call to go thru

Tags: python, sockets

I'm playing around with shadowsocks software, and trying to make the automated adding and deleting function to work, it calls fine, but on next call I get the error `socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use`

```
import socket

cli = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
cli.bind('/tmp/client.sock')  # address of the client
cli.connect('/var/run/shadowsocks-manager.sock')  # address of Shadowsocks manager

cli.send(b'ping')
print(cli.recv(1506))  # You'll receive 'pong'

cli.send(b'add: {"server_port":8001, "password":"7cd308cc059"}')
print(cli.recv(1506))  # You'll receive 'ok'
```

Is it possible to make it close the socket, or make it reuse existing one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the asker would like to remove the server socket, only the client socket.

From the console, this should be enough:

```
rm /tmp/client.sock
```

But you could also do that automatically at the top of the script:

```
import os

if os.path.exists('/tmp/client.sock'):
  os.remove('/tmp/client.sock')
```

[Relevant Github issue](https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev/issues/551)

An improved implementation would:

- Create a unique socket file each time (e.g. `/tmp/ssclient.sock.$PID`)
- Use `try - finally` so it will always remove/unlink the file when the process ends.

Answer (score 0):

try below shell from terminal
`rm -rf /var/run/shadowsocks-manager.sock /tmp/client.sock`

Comment: delete sock file will close associated socket